# Android: Application force closing as soon as it opens

Tags: android

I'm tinkering around with android on Netbeans and did a simple math application. Somewhere along the way the application suddenly force closes as soon as it opens(On the emulator)... I tried commenting all the code in the class that hosts the main activity but to no avail. Since it doesn't give me a specific error message, I feel kind of lost.

Any reason why this is happening?

Here is the layout file as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/number" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/n"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:numeric="decimal"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/calc"
                  android:text="@string/calculate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As suggested I checked logcat and this is the list of errors

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  881): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.me.mathdroid/org.me.mathdroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(NativeMethod)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  881): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1610)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at org.me.mathdroid.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
E/AndroidRuntime(  881):        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your inner <LinearLayout> does not appear to be closed. Try adding an extre </LinearLayout> to the end of your XML file. Also, there's an extra " after the fifth line.

Comment: Removed the quote and the closing tag just wasnt selected as code in the SO editor.

Comment: Posting the stack trace of the exception would help a great deal. Or, if not possible, the "onCreate" block might hold some answers.

Comment: You should definitely post the MainActivity.java source code. Anything where you're calling findViewById.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem was, in the main activity I was setting an Edittext and TextView objects with the ones in the R class, before setting the contentView. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, could you paste the working code here? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Is this on a phone, or in the emulator?  First place I'd look is in the logs.  In Eclipse go to Window > Show View > Other... > Android > LogCat.

You can add your own debug logging messages in your code by

```
Log.d("Debug", "Informative Log Message.");
```

It would also be helpful if you could post your code here.  Post the minimum working code example that exhibits the buggy behavior.

Comment: Thing is I commented all the code of the main activity..so none of my code is being run..What I am assuming is there is something wrong with the strings or layout files

Answer (score 2):

Usually this happens to me when I mess up the layout file. Try opening the main layout file in Eclipse and see if it can still render it. If it can't, that could be the cause of your troubles. Post it here if you will, maybe we can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

try running
`adb logcat`
adb is found in the tools directory in the android sdk, it shows you exceptions during application load, things that can't be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a strings.xml file in your res/values folder? You need to declare the strings that you are using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Test App</string>
    <string name="number">Number</string>
    <string name="calculate">Calculate</string>
</resources>
```

I would recommend using Eclipse rather than Netbeans. Then you can use the ADT plugin to create your layouts which should help you avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

A rather nice way of doing this is to simply add a normal Edit text and then adding:

```
        android:background="@null"
        android:editable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
```

To it
Then simply set the text of the edit text in your class and you should be good to go.